# Get the preview/lightbox URL from SharePoint API from ListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to get the preview URL for various items in SharePoint. When viewing an image, something like this will work:

```
var sharePointServerUri = new Uri( item.Context.Url );
var sharePointFileUrl =
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode( string.Format( "{0}://{1}{2}", sharePointServerUri.Scheme, sharePointServerUri.Host, item.File.ServerRelativeUrl ) );
var lightBoxShareUrl = string.Format( "{0}_layouts/15/Lightbox.aspx?url={1}", sharePointServerUri.AbsoluteUri, sharePointFileUrl );
```

However, this doesn't work for something like a Word document, only images/videos.

Is there a better way to do this which will handle all file types using the SharePoint API?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need the preview/lightbox URL?

Comment: @dorrene-brown That way I can provide a link for someone to click to go straight to the prettier preview page, instead of just loading, say, an image in their browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get a preview link by doing something like this:

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item;
    var wopiFrameUrl = item.GetWOPIFrameUrl( Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWOPIFrameAction.InteractivePreview );
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

And the `wopiFrameUrl.Value` is the preview URL. It seems that it would come back `null` if the `item` is an image, in which case I used the code from the question to construct a LightBox URL.

Comment: It seems Microsoft moved the `SPWOPIFrameAction` enum.  
On your line 3, replace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWOPIFrameAction` with `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.SPWOPIFrameAction`